# Concatenating an asterisk in JList

Tags: java, user-interface, jlist

I have a problem about the concatenation in my asterisk on the `JList`. I have a for loop to concatenate my numbers of asterisk, when you enter 2 the output on my `JList. Here is my code so far.

Comment: Please post only parts of your code that are required for your question.

Comment: What is the problem? What is the expected outcome?

Comment: yes sir . i put a comment on which the code is expected .

Comment: i cant call out the asterisk in the JList . i dont know if i need to put it inside the forloop

Comment: What's the output you want in the `DefaultListModel` when the input is `2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are resetting the text in your field `x` with every loop instead of adding an asterix. Try:

```
for(v=0; v<ce; v++)
{
    x.setText(x.getText() + s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the problem sir .

```
String s = "*";
ce = Integer.parseInt(c.getText());

for (v = 0; v < ce; v++) {
    x.setText(s);
}

list.setSize(60, 60);
//this is the wrong part i cant call it out.
q.add(v.getText() + s + "");
q.add(s.getText());
list.setModel(q);
```

Comment: You can't use the `add` method because it needs 2 arguments. Check the documentation.

Comment: There are two overloaded versions of the `add()` method in `java.​util.​List`, `public boolean add(E e)` and `public void add(int index, E element)`. Therefore, this code snippet is valid.